# Wrapping socketio service in http route handler

Tags: http, go, socket.io

I have a small web server written in go, with http routers, i am trying to wrap a route to a handler that runs a socket.io service, i am not too familiar with socket.io, so i maybe doing something wrong. When i visit my endpoint via browser "localhost:5001/socketio" i am receiving "invalid transport" and getting a "400" in addition the my html isn't being presented on the page which being handled in a separate router.handle , my code, looks like the socketio service isn't even starting:

servio handler

```
func socketio() *socket.Server {

serverio, err := socketio.NewServer(nil)
if err != nil {
    log.Fatal(err)
}

serverio.On("connection", func(so socketio.Socket) {

    log.Println("on connection")

    so.Join("chat")

    so.On("chat message", func(msg string) {
        log.Println("emit:", so.Emit("chat message", msg))
        so.BroadcastTo("chat", "chat message", msg)
    })

    so.On("disconnection", func() {
        log.Println("on disconnect")
    })
})

serverio.On("error", func(so socketio.Socket, err error) {
    log.Println("error:", err)
})

return serverio
}
```

router code

```
func newRouter() *http.ServeMux {
    router := http.NewServeMux()


    router.Handle("/socketio", socketio())
    router.Handle("/", http.FileServer(http.Dir("./asset")))

    return router

}
```

Comment: _When i go to the the end point_ - could you explain it little bit more?

Comment: Edited to be more clear. When running the socket io function standalone in a main func and using a regular http.handle it works as intended. But once wrapped around the webserver and routes it doesn't work

Comment: I think socket.io is particular about its paths. You want to have [your path]/socket.io/ to be the endpoint. And then connect your socket.io client to [your path]/

Comment: I had tried still nothing. Also I should note the HTML I have is not being presented via web browser